# In Ember.js, what's the difference between store save and store commit?

Tags: ember.js

What's the difference between:

```
this.get('store').commit()
```

and

```
this.get('store').save()
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.
`save` is an alias for `commit` that was introduced with this [PR (Make #commit an alias for #save)](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/903)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Not to nit pick intuitivepixel, but isn't it the other way around? Isn't commit an alias for Save? I'm just asking to make sure because I'm new to js + ember world and I'd personally rather use the real deal which in the merge makes it sound like .save is the real thing and .commit is just an alias. Does the rest of the world use .commit?