# How to return validation information from a .save

Tags: json, rest, ember.js, ember-data

With the [DS.RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/), when a ember new data object is created and [saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942614/in-ember-js-whats-the-difference-between-store-save-and-store-commit), a POST request is sent to the server with the json representation of the object.  The server can return a modified the object, but how can it send validation information?

Comment: Server-side Validation in ember-data is work-in-progress. You will have to roll your own I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not official but you can send an errors object back. With the fields that did not validate and a stadus code 422

so with status code 422 content `{"errors": {"foo": "no foo barr"}}`

your record gets an error object with the error messages and data will prevent you from sending update until you altered the fields that have error's

Comment: Thanks.  status code 422 does work with the latest ember-data.  I even get error messages back.